# Multiple IF Statements in DAX

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I currently have Column Data formulated below in Power BI which I need for it to display in one column but replacing the "1" with a Text value being:

Orginal column formula:

```
Age (18-27) = IF(AND([Age]>17, [Age]<28),"1",BLANK())
Age (28-35) = IF(AND([Age]>27, [Age]<36),"1",BLANK())
Age (36-43) = IF(AND([Age]>35, [Age]<44),"1",BLANK())
Age (44-50) = IF(AND([Age]>43, [Age]<51),"1",BLANK())
Age (50+) = IF([Age]>50,"1 ", BLANK())
```

Output:

```
Age (18-27) = IF(AND([Age]>17, [Age]<28),"Age (18-27)",BLANK())
Age (28-35) = IF(AND([Age]>27, [Age]<36),"Age (28-35)",BLANK())
Age (36-43) = IF(AND([Age]>35, [Age]<44),"Age (36-43)",BLANK())
Age (44-50) = IF(AND([Age]>43, [Age]<51),"Age (44-50)",BLANK())
Age (50+) = IF([Age]>50,"Age (50+) ", BLANK())
```

I would like to have the formula display the data in one column where it is consolidating the Output formula (seen above) so I see the results in one column.

Comment: I would like to have the formula display the data in one column where it is consolidating the Output formula (seen above) so I see the results in one column.

Answer (score 8):

Just nest your IFs:

```
Age Group = IF(AND([Age]>17, [Age]<28),"18-27",
 IF(AND([Age]>27, [Age]<36),"28-35",
  IF(AND([Age]>35, [Age]<44),"36-43",
   IF(AND([Age]>43, [Age]<51),"44-50",
    IF([Age]>50,"50+", BLANK())
))))
```

Comment: Thanks @user5226582

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`SWITCH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) like this which is much cleaner than nested IFs:

```dax
Age Group = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    AND([Age]>17, [Age]<28), "18-27",
    AND([Age]>27, [Age]<36), "28-35",
    AND([Age]>35, [Age]<44), "36-43",
    AND([Age]>43, [Age]<51), "44-50",
    [Age]>50, "50+", BLANK()
)
```

Source: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/IF-or-SWITCH/m-p/167098#M72970

Answer (score 2):

Another variation of the SWITCH TRUE pattern:

```dax
Age Group =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    [Age] <  18, BLANK (),
    [Age] <= 27, "18-27",
    [Age] <= 35, "28-35",
    [Age] <= 43, "36-43",
    [Age] <= 50, "44-50",
    [Age] >  50, "50+"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if you want to categorize the column value in the numerical range you can use below dax query.

bubble = IF(AND([no_of_days_pending]>=100, [no_of_days_pending]<200),150,
 IF(AND([no_of_days_pending]>=200, [no_of_days_pending]<300),250,
  IF(AND([no_of_days_pending]>=300, [no_of_days_pending]<400),350,
   IF(AND([no_of_days_pending]>=400, [no_of_days_pending]<500),450,
    IF([no_of_days_pending]>=500,600, BLANK())
))))
```