# How to convert Tableau Calculation to Power BI Calculation

Tags: powerbi

Am trying to create a new column calculation in power bi but am not able to achieve that I have mentioned the tableau code below

*[TIme Duration] is the calculated field
[Time] is a parameter*

```
IF [Ticket Status]='Closed'
THEN 'Closed'
ELSEIF [Ticket Status]='Resolved' AND [TIme Duration]<=[Time]
THEN 'Resolved in ' + STR([Time])+" min"
ELSEIF [Ticket Status]='Resolved' AND [TIme Duration]>[Time]
THEN 'Not Resolved in ' + STR([Time])+" min"
END
```

please help me to convert this calculation to power bi dax Calculation

Comment: I've answered your question but next time put in more effor researching your problem. You're asking a question that has been asked millions of times. All it took was an easy 'Multiple IF statements DAX'

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWITCH() or nested IF():

Taken from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254578/multiple-if-statements-in-dax) post. Just add in your own parameters, use && or AND operator for multiple conditions.

```
Age Group = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    AND([Age]>17, [Age]<28), "18-27",
    AND([Age]>27, [Age]<36), "28-35",
    AND([Age]>35, [Age]<44), "36-43",
    AND([Age]>43, [Age]<51), "44-50",
    [Age]>50, "50+", BLANK()
)
```

Source: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/IF-or-SWITCH/m-p/167098#M72970

Just nest your IFs:

```
Age Group = IF(AND([Age]>17, [Age]<28),"18-27",
 IF(AND([Age]>27, [Age]<36),"28-35",
  IF(AND([Age]>35, [Age]<44),"36-43",
   IF(AND([Age]>43, [Age]<51),"44-50",
    IF([Age]>50,"50+", BLANK())
))))
```